# Do I need to rewrite my client library in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, api, client

For my IOS Application, the client interacts with the server through a fairly substantial client library in C.  I am recreating the app on a website, and I was wondering if I needed to rewrite this library in javascript.  Would it be possible to say, transfer the original static client library to the client through local storage and somehow execute it? Or to download it as a plugin (how would I do this)?  This is just speculation.  Any ideas for a possible solution would be very helpful.  It needs to be client-side because it streams and decodes a video feed through tcp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your IOS is written in which language?

Comment: The client library is written in C

Comment: I would think you would want to decode the video into H.264 or some other codec that the browser understands on the server-side. Try to keep the client as light-weight as possible.

Comment: You have to rewrite your client library in JavaScript, though based on your description of the application that may or may not be possible. You'd probably be better off switching to an industry-standard video feed format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you iOS application uses a library in C the only way (somewhat experimental) is to use [Google Native Client](http://code.google.com/p/nativeclient/) which is a sandboxing technology for running a subset of Intel x86 or ARM native code safely from a web browser. But by now it is only available on Chrome.
Otherwise you have to write it in Javascript in order to be cross platform and run it from nearly every web browsers. Moreover you can modify our iOS application and make it *[hybrid](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wchelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.commerce.starterstores.doc/concepts/csmmobileapphybridi.htm)*, and then you can use the same Javascript library in your iOS application and in the client web browser.

Comment: The same Javascript library, or the same c library?  Also, if I make my app hybrid, it looks like it would only be able to run on Ios Devices.

Comment: If your application is hybrid, then you have to rewrite your C library in Javascript, use it on your iOS application and in your future web browser application.